# Word for a decaying and renewing system, like a coral reef

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

Jungles and coral reefs are built in a piecemeal way: parts of them are always decaying, being patchily replaced by the fresh new bits springing up. The whole ecology acts as a single discordant organism. Whenever I go to old cities I feel the same way — old flats being torn down and replaced by modern buildings, a medley built up over decades.

I’m looking for an adjective to describe something that has been built this way. Any ideas?

I thought “patchwork”, but that does not convey the time-dependency, the fact that it is a process.

Edit 1: In talking with someone about this, I was recommended the word “lapstrake”, which actually refers to a kind of boat, although I like the way it sounds.

Edit 2: I’d also think the word should also convey a sort of messiness, a discord.

Comment: lapstrake ??? I can't see the slightest connection there. That just means clinker-built. (Overlapping planks.)  boatbuilding is a very "fine, detailed" art and it seems the opposite of the "messy, over time" amalgamation you talk of??  I guess you mean the "layers" quality.  Anyways "organic" is the only word I can think of used about cities, as you describe.

Comment: “Self-generative” is a good suggestion, but it doesn’t capture the disorganization or the “colonylike” structure.

Comment: How about "cyclic" system ? Because there is a cycle in ecosystems and it can be applied to cities also.

Comment: [That song from The Lion King](http://youtu.be/HwSKkKrUzUk?t=1m33s) ought to be helpful

Answer (score 3):

What about "organic" - that's sometimes used to describe eg. cities that have the quality you describe.

So, somewhere like "Canberra" is not organic - it was built all of a piece at one time. You could say the same about Paris, Napoleon built it all at once in the one style.

But Tokyo or something is a crazy "organic" city, an amalgamation built over various periods all jumbled together.

Answer (score 1):

If a city was **designed** from a clean sheet, then use **designed.**  If the city began as a small village and later evolved into a city, then use **evolved.**
Note this is specific to a system that can be designed rather than an organic system.

Comment: great thinking ...

Comment: @JoeBlow Thanks, but we still have not addressed the ebb and flow or periodic renewal of an organic system.

Comment: Hey GS, I'm not sure what you mean, but "evolved" (and indeed "organic") are, indeed, words commonly used when describing cities which are the "opposite of Canberra" (Canberra being a "designed" city, as you say).

Comment: @JoeBlow  You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

A word that's missing from this conversation so far:

#### Regenerative: tending to or characterized by regeneration.

[Source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regenerative).

Regenerative does not convey the 'patchwork' aspect which you rightly used to describe natural habitats like coral reefs, but I see no reason you couldn't describe such a habitat as a '*regenerative patchwork*'.

Answer (score 0):

Try *symbiotic* or *parasitic* as starting points of the word search.

If you can step away from biology, **juxtaposition** and **oxymoron** come to mind albeit they are concepts instead of descriptors on physical attributes.

**Asymmetrical** is a more technical term for you.

Answer (score 0):

The term "living system" comes to mind.

To me it implies life, deaths and all that implies.